# My Javascript function to make an Internet Explorer prompt window works when I hit the Submit button but not the Enter key

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer

**UPDATE:** I got it working.  I added the keypress event handler:

```
function keyHit(evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event;
    if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
        blnPwdBoxWait = 'DONE';
    }
    return;
}
```

and add the following line to my password prompt function:

```
objIE.document.addEventListener( "keydown", keyHit, false );
```

The loop that waits for something to happen now looks like this:

```
try {
    do {
        WScript.Sleep( 100 );
        if ( objIE.Visible && blnPwdBoxWait == '' ) {
            blnPwdBoxWait = objIE.document.getElementById( "submitted" ).value;
        }
    } while ( blnPwdBoxWait == '' );
} catch( err ) {
    WScript.Echo('ERROR: ' + err.message);
    blnPwdBoxWait = 'DONE';
}
```

What caused me the most confusion was the fact that I proved (with the use of WScript.Echo statements) that the event handler was catching keystrokes, but the loop wasn't exiting.  I finally realized that I needed to change the line

```
if ( objIE.Visible ) {
```

to

```
if ( objIE.Visible && blnPwdBoxWait == '' ) {
```

to keep the flag variable blnPwdBoxWait from being overwritten to '' when the Enter key was pressed but the Submit button had not been clicked.  Once I made that fix, it worked like a charm.  Thanks for your help!

**ORIGINAL POST:** I have a Javascript function that uses Internet Explorer to open a window that prompts a user for his login ID, password, and target server, and displays a "Submit" button.  It works, but it doesn't do anything when the Enter key is pressed, only when the "Submit" button is clicked.  I tried the usual things like adding an action attribute to the form tag, but nothing I've tried seems to work.  Can anyone tell me what I should do to make the function submit its values when the Enter key is pressed?  Here's a small demo containing the function:

```
True = 1;
False = 0;
aryServers = Array( "server1", "server2", "server3", "server4" );
strDefaultServer = "server2";

objWShell = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" );
strLocalUser = objWShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" );

strPassword = PasswordBox( "Enter Credentials" );
WScript.Echo( "Login ID: " + strLoginID + "\nPassword: " + strPassword +
    "\nServer: " + strServer );

WScript.Exit;

// ===========================================================================

function PasswordBox( strIETitle ) {
    objIE = new ActiveXObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" );
    objIE.FullScreen = False;
    objIE.AddressBar = False;
    objIE.MenuBar = False;
    objIE.StatusBar = False;
    objIE.ToolBar = False;
    objIE.RegisterAsDropTarget = False;
    objIE.Navigate("about:blank");
    strLoginID = strLocalUser;

    do {
        WScript.Sleep( 100 );
    } while ( ! objIE.ReadyState == 4 );

    objIE.document.parentWindow.resizeTo( 400, 300 + 70 );
    objIE.document.parentWindow.resizeTo( 400, 200 + 70 );
    objIE.document.parentWindow.moveTo(
        objIE.document.parentWindow.screen.width / 2 - 200,
        objIE.document.parentWindow.screen.height / 2 - 200 );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<html>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<head>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<title>" + strIETitle + "</title>" );

    objIE.document.writeln( "<style type='text/css'>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<!--" );
    objIE.document.writeln( ".fixed { font-family:courier new, monospace }" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "-->" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</style>" );

    objIE.document.writeln( "</head>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<body bgcolor=Silver>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<center>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<form>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<b>" + strIETitle + "</b><p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<table>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<tr><td colspan=2 align=left>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Enter your username and password:<br>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Username:&nbsp;" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input id='userid' size=20 class='fixed' " +
        "value='" + strLoginID + "'>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Password:&nbsp;" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input type='password' id='passwd' size=20 class='fixed'><p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Remote Host:&nbsp;&nbsp;" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<select id='server'><br>" );
    intLen = aryServers.length;
    for ( intI = 0; intI < intLen; intI++ ) {
        if ( strDefaultServer == aryServers[ intI ] ) {
            objIE.document.writeln( "<option value='" + aryServers[ intI ] +
                "' selected>" + aryServers[ intI ] + "<br>" );
        } else {
            objIE.document.writeln( "<option value='" + aryServers[ intI ] +
                "'>" + aryServers[ intI ] + "<br>" );
        }
    }
    objIE.document.writeln( "</select>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</table>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input type='button' value='Submit' id='but0' " +
        "onclick=\"submitted.value='DONE';\">" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input type='hidden' id='submitted' value=''>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</form>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</center>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</body>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</html>" );
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.scroll="no";
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.style.borderStyle = "outset";
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.style.borderWidth = "3px";
    objIE.document.getElementById( "passwd" ).focus();
    objIE.Visible = True;

    objWShell.AppActivate( strIETitle );

    blnPwdBoxWait = '';
    try {
        do {
            WScript.Sleep( 100 );
            if ( objIE.Visible ) {
                blnPwdBoxWait = objIE.document.getElementById( "submitted" ).value;
            }
        } while ( blnPwdBoxWait=='' );
    } catch( err ) {
        WScript.Echo('ERROR: ' + err.message);
        blnPwdBoxWait == 'DONE';
    }
    strLoginID = objIE.document.getElementById( "userid" ).value;
    strPassword = objIE.document.getElementById( "passwd" ).value;
    strServer = objIE.document.getElementById( "server" ).options( objIE.document.getElementById( "server" ).selectedIndex ).text;
    objIE.Visible = False;
    objIE.Quit();
    objIE = null;

    return strPassword;
}
```

Comment: Is your submit button inside the` <form></form>` tags? It won't work otherwise.

Comment: Change your ``<input type="button"...`` to ``<input type="submit"..``. Also instead of that variable assignment use ``<form onsubmit="myCallbackFunction()"`` to detect when form is submitted. Read http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp. Maybe worth mentioning that if the ``myCallbackFunction`` returns ``false``, the default form submit action is prevented and form is actually not "posted" to server.

Comment: If I change `<input type="button"...` to `<input type="submit"...`, when I run the program and hit the Enter key I get an error message `ERROR: 'objIE.document.getElementByID(...).value' is null or not an object`.  It doesn't work.